# Running multiple features with multiple cucumber tags from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, tags, cucumber

I have the need to run multiple features with multiple tags from Jenkins. So, I have added the below line to the pipeline script in Jenkins, but it doesn't work. Jenkins complains of no scenarios...

```
 sh 'mvn clean verify -Dtarget.env="dev-test" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1 and @tag2"'
```

I tried comma instead of 'and' in vain.

But if I add only one tag it works:-

```
 sh 'mvn clean verify -Dtarget.env="dev-test" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1"'
```

But I need to get it work with multiple tags in order to run multiple features. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide some guidance?

Comment: Try 'or' rather then 'and'.

Comment: If you use `and` then your features are required to have both of these tags. Maybe try `or` as per first comment